# Using a Perl hash

Tags: perl, hash

It's the first time I've used a hash in Perl, and I'm stuck in a weird problem. What I'm trying to do is after I backup files in a directory, I use a Perl program to check if all files appearin the log file. So I had the following code:

```
our (%missing_files) = (); # global definition on the top of the program

... do something ...

sub CheckTarResult {
  my (@dir_list)  = ();  # dir list
  my (@file_list) = ();  # will be filled with all file names in one dir
  my ($j) = "";
  my ($k) = "";          # loop variable
  my ($errors) = 0;      # number of missing files

  ... do something ...

  foreach $j (@dir_list) {

    @file_list = `ls $j`;

    foreach $k (@file_list) {
      $result = `cat $logfile | grep $k`;
      if ($result eq "") {
        $errors++;
        $missing_files{$j} = ${k};
      }
    }
    @file_list = ();
  }

    ... do something ...

  my($dir)  = "";
  my($file) = "";
  while ( ($dir, $file) = each(%missing_files) ) {
    print $dir . " : " . $file;
  }
```

I made an empty log file to do the test, the expecting result should give me all files missing, but somehow "missing_files" only stores the last missing file in each dir. The logic seems to be straightforward, so what am I missing here?

Edit:
I used the advice from @Borodin, and it worked. But in order to print the content of an array reference, we need to loop through elements in the array. The code after the change looks like the following:

```
... everything before is the same ...
push @{$missing_files{$j}}, ${k};  # put elements in dictionary

# in the print statement
while( ($dir, $file) = each(%missing_files) ) {
  for $i ( 0 .. $#$file ) {   # $#$file represents the array size by reference
    print $dir . " : " . ${$file}[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Since `missing_files` refers to a hash, you should replace `$missing_files[$j}` with `$missing_files{$j}`.

Comment: This won't compile, because you have $missing_files[$j} = ${k};  - can you fix it so it's correct?

Comment: Oh that's a typo, fixed. But I guess @Borodin has answered the question below, thx everybody.

Comment: Perl calls it a hash, not a dictionary (edited)

Comment: Just FYI, assigning an empty list in the declaration of a `my` variable is redundant.  `my @array;`, `my (@array);`, and `my (@array) = ();` all do exactly the same thing.  Creating a new variable `@array` with no elements.

Comment: And in general, you should keep your declarations closer to where they are used.  Instead of declaring loop variables at the top of your sub, declare them in the loop `foreach my $k (...) {...}`  And since `@file_list` is only used inside the loop, declare it when you assign to it `my @file_list = qx(ls $j)` and it will fall out of scope by itself at the end of each loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl hash values can contain only a single scalar. If you want to store a list of things then you must make that scalar an array reference. To do that, change the line

```
$missing_files{$j} = ${k};
```

to

```
push @{$missing_files{$j}}, ${k};
```

Comment: Thx for the response, but how do I print the reference? right now it only prints ARRAY(0xd974bf0) (is that a reference appears in perl?) in my print statement.

Comment: @dazhuangcao: Use `print "@{ $array_ref }"`

Comment: `print "$_\n" foreach @{$missing_files{$j}};`